# Redirect with Node Js Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect

I am new to Node JS. I am using it with express and passport. I am also keeping track of the current user from a db.

The goal is for them to not be able to access other data. If they try to access other data, they will be redirected to the correct page of data and be prompted with a message from connect-flash.

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/data/:dataPlace', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    if (req.user.dataPlace == req.params.dataPlace) {
        res.render('data.ejs', {
            user : req.user,
            message: req.flash('dataDisplayMessage')
        });
    }
    else {
        req.flash('dataDisplayMessage', 'OOOPS!');
        res.redirect('/data/' + req.user.dataPlace);
    }
});
```

This works most of the time (even with chrome prefetching data):

```
GET /data/asdasd 302 1.049 ms - 86
GET /data/user 200 1.129 ms - 1639
```

**However**, on the rare occasion I will get something like this:

```
GET /data/asdasd 302 1.108 ms - 86
GET /data/asdasd 302 1.989 ms - 86
GET /data/user 200 2.769 ms - 1646
```

The first GET request is caused by chrome prefetching data. Except, rather than it redirecting right away to 'user' like the previous time, it hangs until I press enter, which then causes another GET request for 'asdasd' and then it redirects to 'user'.

**This causes the message to display twice!**
[image]
So, am I doing this the right way? Why is it displaying the message twice? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it do this in other browsers? Maybe it's a chrome issue? I know that I've had issues with Chrome's prefetch - not really problems, but when you're developing, unexpected requests can cause confusion when trying to find a problem.

Comment: @Kryten I have been trying it with safari and can't seem to reproduce the same result... It would be very sad if there isn't a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a Chrome issue. My temporary solution is to accept the first error message. This is **only** a special case though, as I only have one error message to display to the user at a given time. **This would not be ideal if you have multiple error messages to display, as flash removes all messages once retrieved**

The code was modified in the ejs file:

```
<% if (error.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <%= error[0] %>
        </div>
<% } %>
```